# Scheduled task to run bat via vbs, Task Scheduler says it ran but the bat didn't

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

Not sure where the problem is though. The task originally pointed straight to the bat file but the console window popping up got annoying so I created a vbs script to run the bat file and pointed the task at the vbs instead of the bat.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Path\to\Clue (1985)\random.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

It's supposed to run every five minutes. Task Scheduler reports "The operation completed successfully", but the bat file isn't being run. Manually running the bat gets me the desired result so the bat file itself isn't the issue.

Batch files are really not my area of expertise, and I simply copied the vbs script from something I found on Google looking up how to run the bat without the console window popping up so I know literally nothing about how vbs scripts actually work.

This is the batch file, which works fine when I run it manually:

```
set /a ascii=(%RANDOM% %% 3) + 65
cmd /c exit /b %ascii%

echo Clue (1985) - Ending %=ExitCodeAscii%.mkv > "Clue (1985) - Random Ending.strm"
```

Task is supposed to run every five minutes. I just gave it a manual time trigger to kick it off - it's also set to trigger on system start for the future. I'm the only user account on my PC, so it's running under me, with highest privileges....I think that's everything?

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to have replaced a file path with `[path]`! What is the actual location and content of your batch file. The indication is that the script ran successfully, so I can only assume that your batch file has not preset the working directory, and doesn't use full paths.

Comment: Maybe I don't want to be posting the names of my folders all over the Internet? Unless you have access to my PC to verify that the files are in the right place it's meaningless to you anyway.

Comment: Please think koberulz, and tell me how posting a file path can be a security threat. I'm very security conscious, but I'm afraid that I know of no way by providing a real file path could compromise your perceived security. Also, no it isn't useless at all, for all I know your path is contains one or more characters which cause issues unless dealt with appropriately. It may also not be a fully qualified absolute path, which is the most common issue in questions of this type.

Comment: And besides that, without the content of the batch file we cannot help you to fix an issue with it. So to be clear, your question is currently lacking important information, which is needed for it to be answerable without guessing. If you do not improve it to that effect, the question will soon be closed as off topic. When you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60448380/edit), we also need to see the details of the task you have created for this, especially the user under whom the task is being run, and when the task is being triggered to run, because they're fundemental too.

Comment: Without seeing the batch file and how the Task is setup, it really would be like playing an infinite guessing game.

Comment: It's not a security issue, it's a privacy issue, but I've unobfuscated as much of it as could possibly be relevent. Anything still hidden is alphanumeric characters only. Again, the batch file works perfectly when I run it manually, so to me that eliminates the batch file as a problem, which is why I didn't initially include it.

Comment: I think scheduler executes the vbs and the bat from default directory of the account, which might be different with the expected directory, i.e. everything runs well but you cannot see generated file because it is stored in another directory. Either set exact directory in bat, or set it in scheduled task or set wshshell.currentdirectory="c:\dir...". To test - move vbs in to a new folder and run from there and see where is your generated file.